# Composer not updating modules

Tags: 8, composer

I have a Drupal 8.9.16 website and when I try running `composer update` to update the modules, I get this output

```
$ composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Package container-interop/container-interop is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use psr/container instead.
Package doctrine/reflection is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use roave/better-reflection instead.
Generating autoload files
38 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

So it says *Nothing to install, update or remove*.

Then I look at the list of available updates in the Available updates page (/admin/reports/updates) and most of them have updates.

Looking at the composer.json file, I see it listing the updated version.

For example:

- Drupal's Available updates page says I have *Address 8.x-1.8* installed and
  recommends version *8.x-1.9*.
- The *composer.json* file shows under require: `"drupal/address": "^1.9"`, which I assume means composer says to update to version 1.9.

I was getting this problem in Composer 1, so I updated to Composer 2 but that hasn't changed anything.

```
$ composer --version
Composer version 2.1.3 2021-06-09 16:31:20
```

Below is the content of my composer.json file.

```
{
    "name": "root/chesla",
    "require": {
        "composer/installers": "^1.7",
        "drupal/core": "^8.8",
        "drupal/address": "^1.9",
        "drupal/addtoany": "^1.12",
        "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^2.0",
        "drupal/ajax_form_entity": "^1.0-alpha1",
        "drupal/backup_migrate": "^4.1",
        "drupal/allowed_formats": "^1.2",
        "drupal/block_class": "^1.3",
        "drupal/captcha": "^1.1",
        "drupal/context": "^4.0-beta2",
        "drupal/ctools": "^3.2",
        "drupal/devel": "^2.1",
        "drupal/diff": "^1.0",
        "drupal/entity": "^1.1",
        "drupal/exclude_node_title": "^1.1",
        "drupal/features": "^3.8",
        "drupal/field_group": "^3.0",
        "drupal/media_entity": "^1.8",
        "drupal/imce": "^2.2",
        "drupal/libraries": "^3.0-alpha1",
        "drupal/mailsystem": "^4.3",
        "drupal/image_widget_crop": "^2.3",
        "drupal/markup": "^1.0-beta1",
        "drupal/menu_block": "^1.6",
        "drupal/metatag": "^1.13",
        "drupal/mimemail": "^1.0-alpha2",
        "drupal/module_filter": "^3.1",
        "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.11",
        "drupal/pathauto": "^1.6",
        "drupal/recaptcha": "^2.5",
        "drupal/typed_data": "^1.0-alpha4",
        "drupal/rules": "^3.0.0-alpha5",
        "drupal/sharethis": "^2.0-beta3",
        "drupal/simplenews": "^1.0-beta1",
        "drupal/sitemap": "^1.5",
        "drupal/token": "^1.7",
        "drupal/views_bootstrap": "^4.2",
        "drupal/views_fieldsets": "^3.3",
        "drupal/yoast_seo": "^1.7",
        "drupal/migrate_upgrade": "^3",
        "drupal/migrate_plus": "^4",
        "drupal/migrate_tools": "^4.5",
        "drupal/bootstrap": "^3.21",
        "drupal/context_layout": "^1.0-beta2",
        "drupal/crop": "^2.1",
        "drupal/entityqueue": "^1.0",
        "drupal/views_slideshow": "^4.7",
        "drush/drush": "^10.3",
        "drupal/bootstrap_simple_carousel": "^1.43",
        "drupal/carousel_block": "^1.10",
        "drupal/slick": "^2.3",
        "drupal/webform": "^6.0",
        "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^8.9"
    },
    "repositories": {
        "drupal": {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    }
}
```

I just noticed that I have drush listed.  I don't use it and don't know how to use it.

```
$ drush --version
Drush Launcher Version: 0.6.0
Drush Commandline Tool 10.3.6
```

I am trying to use composer here to update. I can install modules (did webforms the other day).

Thank you.

Comment: Delete the module folder, and run `composer install` to re-install the module. If you still see the same incorrect module version on the page, it probably means the web page you are looking at is for a different instance than the code you are using Composer on.

Comment: I would also check the module's `.info.yml file`, e.g. `address.info.yml` to see what it shows for a version.

Comment: Bear in mind that Composer is only used to update the codebase. You will separately need to interact with Drupal in order for Drupal to become aware of the changes. In the simplest scenario, clearing the site's cache will make Drupal aware of the updated codebase. In some cases, you might also need to update the DB, via `drush updb` or by visiting /update.php on your site.

Comment: All good suggestions. I tried them but didn't work.
[1.] @Jaypan I removed the module folder and ran `composer install`. It re-installed the modules but the Drupal report hasn't changed.
[2.] @sonfd checked the module's .info.yml file and it shows the UPDATED version.
[3.] @Beau Ran /update.php and `drush updb` after clearing the cache and both say there are no updates

Comment: Are you sure you are not working local, and looking at the remote site, or some variation of that? This is the only way that I know of where the displayed version is not the actual version. You can confirm the actual version by looking at `address.info.yml`

Comment: @Jaypan, I think you are on to it.  I removed excess files (copies of the website, backup of the `composer.json` files, etc.) and found I have a second /modules directory at `/sites/default/modules` with the outdated versions while composer changes the modules in `/modules`.  Removing, the modules folder under /sites/default and running `update.php` shows 6 updates now.  Run through that and it shows all (but one) module is up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

Running `composer update` isn't a recommended way to update.

[Here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/updating-drupal/updating-drupal-core-via-composer) you can find a, step by step, recommended way to update your codebase on local and on production.

After a codebase update running a database update is the key here. If you use drush run `drush updb`. If you don't use drush you can visit `[YOUR DOMAIN]/update.php` in any browser.

NOTE: if you visit your site `[YOUR DOMAIN]/update.php` you also might want to change `settings.php`

in `settings.php` set the default `FALSE` to `TRUE` in:

`$settings['update_free_access'] = FALSE; // default`

Comment: I found that the issue was I had a second `/modules` directory in my `/sites/default/` directory with the outdated versions. I deleted the `/sites/default/modules` directory and then Drupal reflected the correct module versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> composer update drupal/address --with-all-dependencies

or

Delete the file composer.lock and Try this:

> composer update

Comment: I found that the issue was I had a second `/modules` directory in my `/sites/default/` directory with the outdated versions. I deleted the `/sites/default/modules` directory and then Drupal reflected the correct module versions.  I'll keep the `--with-all-dependencies` flag in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here (composer updates not being reflected in the Drupal's Available Updates). The problem was as @Hometoy said, two directories. In my case, one was /modules and the other /modules/contrib.
Deleting the module inside /modules and keeping the newer version in /modules/contrib did the trick.